# Matlab Convert quaternion into pure quaternion

Tags: matlab, quaternions

Hi I want to write a matlab function with that I can convert a quaternion into a pure quaternion. A pure quaternion has a zero scalar term.

```
function p_pure_q=q_pure(p)
 p_pure_q = quaternion(0, p(1), p(2), p(3));
end
```

But it did not work and I did not know why. Maybe someone here could give me a hint.

Comment: You need to explain what "did not work" means. E.g., show us an example of input & output and why you think the output is wrong. Or if you got an error message then show that to us. And post the rest of the code you are using so we have a minimum working example. It could be that you are simply assuming the wrong convention (scalar first vs last, or left-chain vs right-chain, etc.) in your code, but we have no way of telling unless you give us more details.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

A unit quaternion is an equivalent represantation for a 3D rotation.

A pure quaternion is simply a 4-tuple normally created by adding a zero at the beginning of a 3D vector.

Such pure quaternion does not represent a rotation at all, but is a mathematical tool to treat 3D vectors when we want to rotate them using quaternions.

For example if `q` is a unit quaternion and `u` is a 3D vector, and if we want to rotate `u` by `q`, then we define `U` as the pure quaternion created through preceding `u` by 0, and then calculate the rotated vector using Hamilton product: `V = q * U * q^{-1}` in which `V` represents the rotated vector `v` preceded by zero.

Comment: I need it for calculating the Hamilton product